# Using Aspect tool in QGIS

Tags: raster, dem, analysis, terrain, aspect

For my bachelor thesis in biology I´m working with QGIS 3.14 (Pi) and tried to create a layer where the slope aspect/expositon/exposure is presented. I´ve got a DTM1 on hands. There is this function of Qgis: raster --> raster terrain analysis --> *aspect*  - with which I was able to create a nicely looking map. The function gives you an azimuth number (between 0-360), which I assigned to the corresponding compass direction. 0-22,5 = N; 67,5 = NE etc.
BUT what I get out of there is certainly not the aspect what it is in nature.
It kinda seems like north and south are inverted sometimes. East and west seem to be ok.
I attach some pictures to show you what I mean.

[image: aspect]

With only *hillshade* on you can see, that the slopes my program is pretending to be north in truth are NOT north. Rather south/east.

[image: hillshade]

Do you have any Idea what could have gone wrong?

This is my GDALinfo:
[image: GDALinfo]

Comment: Did you set your z factor to -1? I never tried but I guess this could invert the results. https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasterterrainanalysis.html?highlight=aspect#aspect

Comment: Try with some open data DEM that others can access easily. For example the GeoServer installation zip http://sourceforge.net/projects/geoserver/files/GeoServer/2.18.0/geoserver-2.18.0-bin.zip contains DEM file "sfdem.tif" in directory data_dir/data/sf. Does the result look odd with this file as well?

Comment: Thank you two so much for your quick reply... user30184 - I downloaded your file and put it into QGIS. From what I can tell from the created hillshade model, It looks fine... no major issues at least... Do you want me to upload pictures of the results?
May it be that my DEM is incorrect or is it rather some of my settings?

Comment: Perhaps there is something special in the DEM. Hard to say by guessing. First step could be to run gdalinfo report about the DEM and add that into your question if you canät share the DEM.

Comment: ok, I´ve added the gdalinfo. The DEM is under a special licence and I guess I´m not allowed to share it... Let me know if there are other infos I can provide. Thank you so much!!! :)